# Do new versions of Jenkins require mandatory log in?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have recently decided to upgrade my fairly old (version 1.5.something) Jenkins server. After I finished the setup and tried to access the url, Jenkins brought up the log in screen.

With my old Jenkins, I was only required to log in if I needed to access managing section. Is this a new feature of mandatory log in or is this just some configuration that I can change?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so: you can define authorizations and decide which permissions 'Anonymous' has.